# Get a reference from an iframe to its parent webcomponent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web-component

I have a webcomponent that hosts an iframe. From within the iframe, I want to refer to its parent webcomponent.

I would expect that this does the trick (from within the iframe):

```
parent.document
```

However, this gets me a reference to the outer parent

```
main             <- iframe.parent.document
└──webcomponent  <- I need this
   └──iframe
```

Is this a (Chrome) bug or is this expected behavior?